# Как нужно правильно указывать пути?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть javascript код (или это jquery, я пока их не различаю), который выводит/прячет информацию в зависимости от адреса страницы.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                if ( location.pathname == "/" || location.pathname == "/pct_") {$('.kalf').hide();}
            else { $('.kalf').show();}
            });
```

Этот код я понимаю так:

если (путь равен "адресу сайта" или путь совпадает с "вложенной папкой pct_"), {то скрыть всё относящиеся к классу kalf}
иначе {показывать}

Вопрос:

1. А если требуется указать не точный адрес? например pct_ это только часть названия -  index.html/pct_123 или index.html/pct_34255,  или index.html/pct project0001 и тд
2. А если в папке pct_123 есть вложенные страницы или подпапки на которых тоже нужно скрыть?
3. А если нужно сделать обратные действия, то есть применить код не к перечисленным страницам, а ко всем кроме указанных?
4. А если pct_ не первая подпапка, а под-под папка?

Мои варианты

по первому пункту мой вариант точно не работает)))

```
if ( location.pathname == "/" || location.search = "/pct_?") {$('.kalf').hide();}
```

по второму пункту даже предположений нет как это можно написать
по третьему пункту хотела поменять равно на неравно, но тогда нужно будет перечислять все страницы, а если их сотни.... наверняка должен быть вариант попроще

```
if ( location.pathname != "/" || location.pathname != "/pct_" || location.pathname != "/pct_123" и тд) {$('.kalf').hide();}
```

по четвертому пункту предположила, что такое сработает, но нет

```
if ( location.pathname == "/" || location.pathname == "/../pct_") {$('.kalf').hide();}
```

Comment: `А если требуется указать не точный адрес? например pct_ это только часть названия` если все же хотите именно на фронте реализовать такое(или бэка у вас просто нет), для подобным образом размытых целей регулярки хороши(впрочем, на бэке для этих целей он тоже пригодится. тот же mod_rewrite на них). по сути регулярки это отдельный довольно мощный "недо-пере-язык", насколько мощный, настолько же и тяжелый для освоения\восприятия. хотя это и не `brainfuck` конечно, но все равно - удачи в знакомстве :3

Comment: puffleeck, спасибо большое за пояснение

Comment: `location.pathname` это строка. Все что вам нужно, это проверить, удовлетворяет ли строка заданным условиям. Можно воспользоваться методом строки `indexOf`, который ищет вхождение подстроки в строке.

Comment: SwaD, спасибо вам за подсказку и с наступающим нг)))
Простите не могу плюсануть ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> если требуется указать не точный адрес

Нужно искать по подстроке. Это может быть сделано например через [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

2.

> А если в папке pct_123 есть вложенные страницы или подпапки

Js работает на клиенте. Проверка на "подпапки" должна быть **на сервере**

3.

> А если нужно сделать обратные действия

Для этого есть знак `!` в программировании, который может ставиться до условия (например `if (!test) { ... }`). Надо учить основы

4.

> А если pct_ не первая подпапка, а под-под папка

Аналогично второму пункту

---

> если их сотни

нужно смотреть на цели и задачи. В каком-то достаточно ориентироваться  на часть пути, в каком-то придётся составить массив путей и проверять на вхождение через [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), в какой-нибудь другой задаче ещё как-либо

Comment: Вообще ничего не поняла, кроме пункта "на js это сделать нельзя, только на стороне сервера".

Ответ рассчитан на людей, которые уже в теме, но не забывайте, что есть люди кто только начинает этот путь и такие ответы лично для меня не несут никакой поясняющей информации.

Comment: Вполне всё понятно. Если вам непонятно выражение "искать по подстроке" и вы не умеете по ссылке переходить, в которой написано применение функции - ну уж извините ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Для вас любой ответ будет непонятен, потому что вы не читали ни одной книги для новичков. И вам нужно вначале их почитать. А там почти вся информация, которая представлена в вопросе - имеется

Comment: Вот уважаемый SwaD в своём коротком комментарии смог донести больше полезной информации для меня как для новичка.

Comment: @Настёна понимаю. Фраза "искать по подстроке" намного понятнее, чем "искать по подстроке". Логично.  \*рукалицо*